# Covering a creepy old tile ceiling

Tags: ceiling

I've been researching ways to 'fix' a large area (20x40) of old glued-in 10'inch square acoustic tiles on the ceiling in my house that I am renovating. No idea what is above the tiles (the house is over 100 years old) and I don't have the budget right now to spend much on fixing this up.

I am considering placing 1/4 inch drywall over the tiles (leaving them in place) using both construction glue and long screws). I could then add in wood trim pieces every 2 feet or so to add some architectural interest as well as additional support for the drywall.

Does this sound like a reasonable solution? Eventually, I will remove the entire ceiling and depending on what I find up there doing something different..the original ceiling was at 12 feet, but now it is at 8 feet and the other rooms in the house still have the 12 foot ceilings. But, replacing 20 windows is eating into my budget right now.

Thanks for any help or comments.

Comment: Please do a search on [Asbestos ceiling tiles](https://www.google.com/search?q=asbestos+acoustic+ceiling+tiles&oq=asbestos+acoustic+ceiling+tiles&aqs=chrome..69i57.12265j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Part of the difficulty is what are you going to screw into? Do you know where the ceiling joists and beams are? Screws into just acoustic tiles will do almost nothing.

Comment: Do you know how the ceiling is suspended? I know in some cases T bar frames were installed and suspended by wires. I am not sure this type of ceiling could handle the extra weight of sheet rock.

Comment: Hmm, it's *creepy*, it's old and it's 20x40x4 feet worth of space. Worrisome. Call those darn kids in the van with the dog. Jinkies.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the kind of ceiling tiles. My inspector told me that the ones in my place are a variety that would indeed let me screw drywall in place directly over them. That isn't going to be true of all types, and I don't know how to tell what type one has just by looking.

(I too have a mix of ceiling heights, but that is because the house was built in two stages 50 years apart and the conventions differed. There is an area where the renovations overlapped the old house and the ceiling was lowered, admittedly; basically just the dining room and part of the kitchen.)

Answer (score 0):

Laminate it with 1/4" sheetrock. Glue the back of the panels with construction adhesive and use hi/low rock to rock screws. You'll be fine